# How to assign character array to string in the most elegant manner?

Tags: delphi, syntax

I love Pascal for its clarity, so believe what the following code snippet along with question title is self-explanatory:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  N = 42; { fnord }
type
  { this structure merely defines memory layout }
  TStringStruct = record
    NumberOfCharacters: Cardinal;
    { this array supposed to be friendly for the string type }
    StringCompatibleArray: array [0..N-1] of Char;
  end;
  { actual work is done with pointer to that structure }
  PStringStruct = ^TStringStruct;
var
  StringStruct: PStringStruct;
  S: string;
begin
  StringStruct := PopulatedElsewhere;

  { most pleasant code but will copy no more than N characters }
  S := StringStruct^.StringCompatibleArray;

  { this construct works but is way too ugly and complex }
  SetString(
    S,
    { in particular: must reference the array and then typecast to make it work }
    { default $T- state assumed, unfortunately $T+ has global effect and not useful here }
    PChar(@StringStruct^.StringCompatibleArray),
    StringStruct^.NumberOfCharacters
  );
end;
```

In case someone wants formal question: i'd like to see which options i have to perform such assignment, preferably less obscure than shown `SetString` call.

Note: i know what dereference operators are optional with structured types.

Comment: Looks like you are implementing some Pascal string like thing. You could try it with a operator overloading. Overload implicit and explicit cast operators. P.S. Good work on the Electorate badge!

Comment: In case you're not aware; you can comment out a single line of code using double backslash instead of surrounding with braces e.g. "// this structure merely defines memory layout"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SetString` is the way to go, ordinarily. It's only obscure if people continue to remain ignorant about its usefulness. The type casting is necessary because there are two overloads, and the char array doesn't *exactly* match either expected argument type (PAnsiChar and PWideChar).

It's wordy, but in your case it's easily wrapped into a function for your data type, like `ToString`. As David suggested in a comment, you can let that function be the `Implicit` operator, and then you get the conversion automatically:

```
class operator TStringStruct.Implicit(const Value: TStringStruct): string;
begin
  SetString(Result, Value.StringCompatibleArray, Value.NumberOfCharacters);
end;

S := StringStruct^;
```

Comment: Yeah, sometimes overloads are adding complexities rather then solving them. Got your point on matching types, thanks.

Comment: Operator approach looks quite elegant, but could you please clarify: a) will class method disturb memory layout of struct? b) can i use something like class helper to isolate instrumented struct? c) minimum compiler version requirement for record operators is BDS2006, right?

Comment: Class operators, like class methods, have absolutely no effect on type layouts. They're just ordinary standalone functions, but with special scope. Class helpers are only allowed for classes, not records, and wouldn't be appropriate here anyway.